# Как создать .Net Core 3 WPF приложение в VisualStudio 19?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

При попытке создать WPF приложение на .Net Core 3 выдает это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я думаю, что тут проблема локализации, ибо найти такие разделы настроек не могу. Смотрел в ютубе у людей, которые создавали WPF на .Net Core 3, они ставили галочку в "Параметры" - "Проекты и решения"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но у меня там нет такого пункта: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сама vs 2019 должна быть последней Preview версии

Comment: Какой версии VS пользуетесь? `.NET Core 3.0 should be used with the latest previews of Visual Studio.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В VS 2019 эту опцию перенесли в параметры окружения (Окружение, Environment). Нижняя из двух галочек на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть еще одна проблема, требуется последняя **предварительная (preview)** версия VS 2019, об этом есть предупреждение на странице загрузки .NET Core.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создать проект WPF App Core на релизной версии ни какие опции так и не позволили.